# How do I write a file to a nonspecific user's desktop on C?

Tags: c, file, filepath

I wrote a program and I wanted it to write a file to the Desktop. I figured out how to write it to mine, but I want it to be able to go to anybody's desktop (windows).

Is there a way to make the path name more dynamic so it can work on anybody's desktop?

This is a sample:

```
void add(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Jones\\Desktop\\test.txt", "w+");
    float num1;
    float num2;
    float sum;
    printf("Enter first number: ");
    num1 = getNum();
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    num2 = getNum();
    sum = num1 + num2;
    printf("%.1f + %.1f = %.1f\n", num1, num2, sum);
    fprintf(fp, "Num1: %.1f\nNum2: %.1f\nSum: %.1f ", num1, num2, sum);
    fclose(fp);
    while(getchar() != '\n')
    {
                continue;
    }

}
```

Comment: If the answer was `sprintf` then it's not a dup of that windows API thing. Maybe it's a dup of something else.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes. Use `sprintf`. It's like `fprintf` but for strings.

```
char fname[256];
sprintf(fname, "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\test.txt", "Jones");
fopen(fname, ...
```

Comment: This is wrong. The Desktop may not be found under this location. Use the Windows API to find the proper path instead of hardcoding assumptions.