# How to create file for any user(any computer) desktop in c ?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a `c` program that creates a file for any computer user. But my program only works for my current user. Not for all users. How can i solve it? I am using windows 10. Please help me.

```
    FILE *fpt;
    fpt = fopen("C:\\Users\\Zobayer\\Desktop\\C File IO\\example.txt","r");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a file to a nonspecific user's desktop on C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644618/how-do-i-write-a-file-to-a-nonspecific-users-desktop-on-c)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more simple windows-based way of doing this, but you could just keep an array of all users on your machine that you want to add the file to.

Pseudo code here, but where you need write to the file in your program it'd be something like this:

```
char ** listofusers = {"Zobayer","Tim","Andrea"};

 for (i=0;i<sizeof(listofusers);i++) {
    writeToUsersDesktop(listofusers[i]);
    }
```

and then writeToUsersDesktop() would just take the user's name and format it to a string something like `"C:\\Users\\\s\\Desktop\\SomeCommonFolder"`
Then it would take that string and use it as an argument in fopen()

NOTE: This is not a safe way of doing this if you're asking for user input for the list of users unless you sanitize the usernames first.